# Is every vector space a banach space?

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Using the axiom of choice one can show that for each ($\mathbb{R}$-) vector space $V$ there exists a function $\|\cdot\| : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space.

So I wondered: Does there also for each ($\mathbb{R}$-) vector space $V$ exist a norm $\|\cdot\|$ so that $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ is a banach space? If yes, why? If not, can we construct a counter example?

I would love to add a “what I have already tried” section here, but sadly I do not know what to try. (I just *feel* this should be false and therefore hope for a nice counter example.)

Comment: There are non-complete normed vector spaces.

Comment: For instance, $L^p$ norm on $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$. Does this address your question?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, of course. But that does not prove that there does not exist another norm, which might be complete.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: See the comment above. For $C([0,1])$ there cleary exists a norm so that the space becomes a Banach space, namely the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm

Comment: @keba my bad, I underestimated and/or misread the question, that's why I wasn't sure about helpfulness.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi: No need to apologize, maybe my wording was also not that perfect. :)

Answer (score 7):

No. The baire category theorem guarantees that no normed space with dimension equal to the cardinality of the natural numbers can be a Banach space.

Comment: I remember doing that exercise.  What about cardinalities besides that of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Well every norm on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, and as a consequence they are all complete. For dimension strictly greater than that of the natural numbvers, there are examples of complete and incomplete normed spaces

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer (although I have to google the theorem, I have not taken a fa course yet). :) Can you give an example for a vector space with dimension $\aleph_0$?

Comment: Ahh! I just take the span of countable many linear independent vectors.

Comment: The easiest example is the space $c_{00}$ of all complex sequences such which are 'eventually zero'; i.e. sequences with only finitely many non-zero entries. The completion of this space under various norms gives the classical sequence spaces $\ell^p$ which you will undoubtedly meet in your course.

Comment: @SamM: Which is the span of $\{(e_{n,k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $e_{n,k} = \delta_{n,k}$, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  (Note that the span is all finite linear combinations.)